# Upload de arquivo PDF

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

Preciso de fazer um upload de arquivos pdf com angular js.

Tenho campo um para o usuario inputar um arquivo, porém como envio esse arquivo pro back end e salvo ele em alguma pasta?

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente você precisa recuperar o *base64* do arquivo selecionado no `<input>`, e mandar ele para seu server usando o `$http.post`.

Basicamente eu aprendi vendo este componente publicado no github,

visite https://github.com/mistralworks/ng-file-model

Com ele você precisaria apenas de ter o `<input>` da seguinte maneira

```
<input type="file" ng-file-model="testFile" />
```

Em que *testeFile* seria sua variavel angular no scope.

No `ngController` você acessaria o *base64* da seginte maneira:

```
var base64 = $scope.testFile.Data
```

Este `Data` é gerado pelo componente que te mandei o link, agora basta enviar o

*base64*  para seu servidor.

Comment: @Rodrigo K.B eu fiz dessa maneira e recebi um error dizendo que o arquivo era muito grande. eu queria saber se tem um jeito de baixar esse arquivo em alguma basta no meu projeto? obrigado pela resposta

Comment: @Gabriel.H quem retornou o erro? O seu banco de dados ou o servidor?  Se você estiver conseguindo chegar ao servidor, você pode converter o *base64* em arquivo e salvar na pasta. Caso o servidor que esteja dando erro, provavelmente deva ser configuração. Quer tipo de server você usa? C#, node.js?

Comment: O servidor me retornou que o arquivo é muito grande

Comment: Esse erro provavelmente é configuração do seu servidor. Você usa qual linguagem no server?

Comment: O servidor é escrito em PHP

Comment: Você tem que procurar como configurar o seu servidor php para mudar o limite do tamanho que ele aceita receber. Isso é normal para todo server. Eu não entendo de PHP, então não consigo te ajudar.

Comment: Ok, já foi de grande ajuda, obrigado